# How to show zf2 errors?

Tags: error-handling, nginx, zend-framework2

I've reinstall my system and now when something wrong in zf2 i cant see the error on the page only in nginx error log, the display_errors   On and  display_startup_errors  On, in php.ini, maybe something with my php-fpm settings?
And in the simple php file not in zf2 i have see the errors!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ini_set('display_errors', true);` in my index.php now show me the errors

Comment: Put `ini_set('display_errors', true);` at the beginning of your `config/autoload/local.php` file.

*Don't put it in your `index.php` file* since this would enable errors in your production environment too.

Answer (score 12):

You need enable the following options in your config

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
)
```

Remember turn off this in a production environment

Comment: @Cawa you got a wrong `error_reporting` or `display_errors` setting in your php.ini

Answer (score 3):

Zend framework 2 will merge configs from **all loaded modules**, so you need to ensure that you already set 'display_exceptions' (if that key exists) to true in **all** modules's config file.

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
)
```

You can see which modules are loaded in your application.config.php file

Comment: Or you could set this value to `true` in the last loaded module (your own app). This will override all others.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the above with an environment check:

Add this to your public/index.php at the top:

```
$env = getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'production';
if($env == "development") {
  error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
  ini_set('display_errors', true);
}
```

And this one to your public/.htaccess:

`SetEnv "APP_ENV" "development"`

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your public/index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: nothing happens, i've tryed it already, and i i tell you the reporting is on in php.ini and i see them in another php files not zf2, for it only i have erorlog, but not on the page

Comment: after changed php.ini, did you have restarted nginx/apache service?

Comment: also, print a phpinfo() and check the php.ini path please, make sure the file you edit is correct one

Comment: I don't think these small details are stupid, if you install php-fpm by apt-get, you will have several php.ini in systems, edit the correct one is necessary. Also please check if you have restarted php5-fpm service

Comment: look at my question, do you see the answer to what you asked me to do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18965/discussion-between---and-allovince)

Comment: @Саша Харьков Being rude and aggressive to people who are trying to help you is not going to get you very far. Nobody here has to help you, so calm down and answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Zend errors and NGinX - php5 fpm, work like this:

Only I put in `public/index.php` (@AlloVince)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Without `If(){...}`

But If only to put above code, display error, will give this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in /usr/local/nginx/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumController.php on line 12
```

Another thing! Set up this code: (@To Nong)

```
'display_not_found_reason' => true,
'display_exceptions'       => true,
```

in `module.config.php` like this:

```
'view_manager' => array(
 'template_path_stack' => array(
     'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
     'display_not_found_reason' => true,
     'display_exceptions'       => true,
 ),
```

),

I get all errors of an error log on screen:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid path provided; must be a string, received boolean' in /usr/local/nginx/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Resolver/TemplatePathStack.php:201 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/nginx/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Resolver/TemplatePathStack.php(149): Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack->addPath(true) #1 /usr/local/nginx/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Service/ViewTemplatePathStackFactory.php(38): Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack->addPaths(Array) #2 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewTemplatePathStackFactory->createService(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'viewtemplatepat...', 'ViewTemplatePat...') #3 /usr/local/nginx/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(939): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend in /usr/local/nginx/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 946
```

I didn't touch config file as php-fpm in system (Ubuntu 14.04).