# ZF2 Doctrine2 DQL... how can I find out what's wrong?

Tags: debugging, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I created simple Action based on [this tutorial](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) (the same entities and stuff).

```
$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
$dql = "SELECT b, e, r FROM Bug b JOIN b.engineer e JOIN b.reporter r ORDER BY b.created DESC";

$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$query->setMaxResults(30);
$bugs = $query->getResult();
```

And now Zend just throws 500 without any information. By commenting the lines I found out that tha problem occures on `$bugs = $query->getResult();` line but I have no information - just 500 (even apache error log is empty). Are there any tools for debug?

Comment: If you get a generic 500 error you'll need to [ensure PHP is displaying error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php), and [configure ZF2 to display execptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193550/how-to-show-zf2-errors#answer-13195157).

Comment: But how can I do this if even `ini_set` and `error_reporting` in this specific method doesn't do the job?

Comment: Once you have your `$query`, does it work if you call `getSQL()` on it? If it does not work then you have an issue with your query syntax, maybe the `FROM Bug b` part: are you sure `Bug` is a fully qualified name for this entity? Anyway @AlexP is probably right: some error output must be hidden by some configuration ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check if error reporting/show exceptions is properly configured to render errors/exceptions just like @Moby04 suggested.

You should check for example if you have these lines in your application config array:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true, 
    'display_exceptions'       => true, 
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404', 
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index', 
)
```

And make sure that the template values actually map to 'proper' view templates.