# Zend Framework 2 Additional error information missing in local setup

Tags: zend-framework2

I set up zend app, I got 500 error  with message

```
An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
```

Missing Additional information part

do I need to setup dev environment variable or something?

I can't figure out the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could display more information about the error by setting php error displaying to true directly in your `php.ini` file, or in your `index.php` file.

In the `index.php` file, you could do that as follows :

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

**EDIT :**

Also make sure to set `display_exceptions` to `true` in your `module.config.php` file :

```
<?php
  return array(
  //...

 'view_manager' => array(    
 'display_not_found_reason' => true,
 'display_exceptions'       => true, //set this parameter to true
  
 //...
```

Comment: error reporting is enabled, I can see all normal php errors, but if  I enter the wrong database password, its not returning Additional information, it might be something do to zend error handler?

Comment: So make sure this line to set `display_exceptions` to **true** in your `module.config.php` file.

Comment: It worked with display exceptions, thanks

but is there any way to setup only in local setup files, so it won't go in live server code?

Comment: like adding extra config file module.local.php to see exceptions in only development

Comment: Ok, I see. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193550/how-to-show-zf2-errors#answer-22013059 I think this is what you're looking for.